# Select multiple items in ListBox programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, multi-select

I'm trying to select ListBox items through C#. I am not able to select multiple items, it always select the last value which is in my selected items list.

I tried to loop through each `ListBoxItem` and check if it exists in my selected items list or not.

```
 List<int> SelectedItems = new List<int>();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con)
 con.Open();
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (dr.Read()) {
   SelectedItems.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["RecordId"].ToString()));
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < listbox.Items.Count; i++) {
     int x = Convert.ToInt32(listbox.Items[i].Value.ToString());
     if(SelectedItems.Contains(x)){
     listbox.SelectionMode = listbox.Multiple;
     listbox.SelectedIndex = i;
     }
  }
```

I need to select multiple items not only the last selected value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `SelectedIndex` property, try adding items with `listbox.SetSelected` with `listbox.SetSelected(x,true);`

Comment: `SetSelected` is not supported.

Comment: @ArmaanLabib what do you mean by "is not supported"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
LblDisplay.Text = "";
lstPromote_products.SetItemChecked(4, true);
chkRestricted.Checked = true;
```